# I am trying to connect to a sftp server using Zehon api.. but everytime it gives me "permission denied" error... what am i doing wrong here?

Tags: java, sftp

```
    InputStream is = null;
    byte[] data = xDto.toString().getBytes();
```

try {

```
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

        int status = SFTP.sendFile(is, nameOfFile, destFolder, host, username, password);

        if(FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS == status){
            System.out.println(" got sftp-ed successfully to  folder "+destFolder);
        }
        else if(FileTransferStatus.FAILURE == status){
            System.out.println("Fail to sftp  to  folder "+destFolder);
        }
    } catch (FileTransferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

THe error is:

```
com.zehon.exception.FileTransferException: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not create file "(path of file)".
    at com.zehon.FileTransferClient.sendFileStreamHelper(FileTransferClient.java:316)
    at com.zehon.FileTransferClient.sendFile(FileTransferClient.java:287)
    at com.zehon.sftp.SFTPClient.sendFile(SFTPClient.java:281)
    at com.zehon.sftp.SFTP.sendFile(SFTP.java:110)
    at com.stud.main.CreateFileUsingFtp.main(CreateFileUsingFtp.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not create file "(path of file)".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.createFile(AbstractFileObject.java:916)
    at com.zehon.FileTransferClient.sendFileStreamHelper(FileTransferClient.java:301)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not create folder "(folder name)".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.createFolder(AbstractFileObject.java:969)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.createFolder(AbstractFileObject.java:952)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.getOutputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1390)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.getOutputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1353)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.createFile(AbstractFileObject.java:906)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: 3: Permission denied
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2289)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.mkdir(ChannelSftp.java:1699)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.sftp.SftpFileObject.doCreateFolder(SftpFileObject.java:195)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.createFolder(AbstractFileObject.java:958)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: I assume you can ssh to the host from the command line using the same credentials. e.g. username/password.

Comment: yes.. of course... i used filezilla :)

Comment: I would test you can `ssh user@host mkdir directory-of-file` first.  It may be that the user doesn't make permissions to create the directory.  After you create the directory, it shouldn't be trying to recreate it anyway.

Comment: I am able to create folder manually through filezilla.... but its not getting created through code above..

Comment: can anyone here tell me the answer?